# Webjob always publishes as Continuous and not Triggered

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have an Azure WebJob which I am publishing from visual studio 2017 to a Standard S1 App Service, the WebJob should be Triggered by CRON but always publishes as Continuous and I cannot figure out what I have done wrong (two other WebJobs publish fine)

I have the App Service set to 'Always On' in application settings
[image]

I have a settings.job file in the root with my schedule

```
{
     "schedule": "0 3 5 * * 1-5"
}
```

[image]

My Program class

```
namespace EventPushUpdater
{
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using MBL.AzureKeyVaultHelpers;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Properties.Settings s = Properties.Settings.Default;

            IKeyVault kv = new KeyVaultHelper(s.ClientId, s.ClientKey, s.KeyVaultRoot);

            var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
            config.DashboardConnectionString = kv.GetSecretValue(s.DashboardConnectionString);
            config.StorageConnectionString = kv.GetSecretValue(s.DashboardConnectionString);            
            var host = new JobHost(config);

            host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("PushEvents"), new { keyVault = kv });
        }
    }

}
```

And the function being called

```
public class Functions
{
    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static void PushEvents(IKeyVault keyVault)
    {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first time you chose 'Publish as a WebJob', it asks you if you want Continuous or On Demand (which includes scheduled):

[image: WebJob publish]

If you picked the wrong choice, simply delete `webjob-publish-settings.json` under Properties, and try again.

As an aside, your code is overly complex as you're needlessly using WebJobs **SDK**. Instead, your code can simply be:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can switch between 'Continuous' and 'Triggered' modes by editing the webjob-publish-settings.json file that is found within the Properties folder of your WebJob project.

[image: webjob-publish-settings.json]

In this json file you can set **"runMode:"** to either *Continuous* or *OnDemand* (triggered) :

### Continuous

[image: Continuous]

### OnDemand

[image: Triggered]

Answer (score 1):

Have you set `{ "is_singleton": true }` in your `settings.job`?
If so you cannot run more than one instance of your WebJob. If you publish and run your WebJob to the Azure cloud you cannot never run it locally unless you use a different storage account.

[Azure Webjob timer trigger does not fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296109/azure-webjob-timer-trigger-does-not-fire)