# Azure Timer Trigger webjob: Function is being recognised but not being triggered

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, timer-trigger

I have an Azure timer trigger webjob, deployed in two different environments with two different storage accounts. The webjobs have been deployed for about two months now, and were running as expected for quite some time. However, for about a week now, the function is being recognised but not being executed.

Here is how the logs look:

```
Found the following functions:
ADFSchedulerWebJob.Functions.ProcessTimerMessage
Job host started
```

Nothing happens after the Job host is started, i.e., the function ProcessTimerMessage is not called/executed. This is how the function looks:

```
public static void ProcessTimerMessage([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo info, TextWriter log)
    {
        //function logic
    }
```

This is how the Main method looks like:

```
static void Main()
    {
            JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
            config.UseTimers();
            var host = new JobHost(config);
            host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

The same is occurring even when I try to debug the webjob locally. What could be the possible reason/resolution?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us some (relevant) code? Mainly interested in the TimerTrigger cron expression.

Comment: Edited the question to include function signature containing TimerTrigger CRON expression.

Comment: Did you add `config.UseTimers();` in the main method?

Comment: Yes, added the main method in the question above for reference.

Comment: This webjob was functioning as expected up till a few days ago. No new code has been committed to the webjob but it has started showing these problems only now.

Comment: Are you using the same storage account for another webjob or another environment ? Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296109/azure-webjob-timer-trigger-does-not-fire

Comment: Turns out this was the problem. Although I had taken care to make the config read values from the key share, the key in the key share itself had incorrect value.  The keys in both the environments were set to the same storage account, hence the issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What could be the possible reason/resolution?

As Thoms mentioned that it seems that the same storage account is used for another webjob or others.

We could debug it with following ways:

1.Try to use another storage account

2.Check the webjob log from the storage

We could get more info about Webjob log from the [blog](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/03/14/azure-webjob-logs-demystified/).

Comment: Turns out this was the problem. Although I had taken care to make the config read values from the key share, the key in the key share itself had incorrect value.  The keys in both the environments were set to the same storage account, hence the issue. Thanks for the help.