# Azure Trigger Function does not schedule in Slots (preview)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a function app with three Timer Trigger functions in it. I want to use the staging/production functionality provided by the Slots (preview), so I set up the VSTS deployment for two separate branches. The primary function app polls master and the slot polls a branch called staging.

The problem is that when I start the function app, the main functions schedule and run, but the Slot functions don't seem to get scheduled to run at all. Things I've tried:

- I set the hosts.json file for each with a separate 'id' field to avoid a conflict on the locks that determine whether or not they can run. Looking in the storage account, I can see a folder for each app (the main and the slot) and a folder for each function, which I think means they shouldn't be using the same locks.
- Use a separate storage account for the Slot app
- Stop the main function app while keeping the Slot app running

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong with my setup or if there's a known bug with Slots (preview) preventing this from working?

Comment: sounds related tot his question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296109/azure-webjob-timer-trigger-does-not-fire/. Maybe you can try to specify a different HostId in the `host.json` file  ? dont know if it os possible

Comment: I guess you can configure different storage accounts for each slot ??

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I did state in the question that I am already using two different host ids: one in each file. Is there a separate field from "id" called "HostId"?

Comment: @Thomas I neglected to mention I already tried using two completely separate storage accounts and that did not work either. I updated the post to clarify what I've tried

Comment: I am gonna have a look, not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: What's the result if you just deploy staging branch (slot related)? What's the result if you deploy the app manually (e.g. Through Visual Studio)?

Comment: What're detail steps to reproduce this issue?