# Is it possible to create a Azure Function Bot with the v4 SDK that use bot state?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-functions

I tried to build this example https://github.com/brandonh-msft/botbuilder-functions with the stable version of Microsoft.Bot.Builder v4, but I encoutered problems creating ConversationStore, all .NET samples for v4 requires a ASP.NET Core web application which obviously does not apply for Azure Functions.

And exist this nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Core.Extensions/4.0.1-preview, but is in preview, and i don't know if will be deprecate or update

Comment: Could you check this post, I guess it is related to some lock at the function host level https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296109/azure-webjob-timer-trigger-does-not-fire

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you making a Functions bot instead of a web app bot?

Comment: Did you try [Functions V2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-functions-2-0/)? If yes can you please give more details on the issues you are running into?

Comment: because i´m testing bot in serverless infraestructure.

Comment: yes, im making it with that version, i resolved writting a middleware all my own, but i would like use the bot framework's classes, and all the help are for asp net core

Comment: The issue is for configure the bot state, all doc says that writing in startup.cs but in fuctions not exists

Answer (score 0):

According to Azure portal,

> Bot Framework SDK v4 is now available and comes with many updates and new functionality. Function Bots are based on SDK v3; we recommend you create a Web App Bot instead, which supports the new SDK v4.

You can set up state store (blob or tables) on a functions bot, but only currently with the v3 SDK.